# Why "npm run android" is giving Error in React Native project?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, npm

I am new to React Native. I'm trying to run a project.
after running npm run android i'm getting the following error:

```
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava

> Configure project :app
Unable to detect AGP versions for included builds. All projects in the build should use the same AGP version. Class name for the included build object: org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuild$IncludedBuildImpl_Decorated.

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
Native libs debug enabled: false
Android gradle plugin: 7.0.4
Gradle: 7.3.3
building Reanimated2
C/C++: Could not execute cmake at '/usr/local/bin' to get version. Skipping.
[CXX5304] This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 2 but an SDK XML file of version 3 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
[CXX5304] unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
[CXX5304] unexpected element (uri:"", local:"extension-level"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
[CXX5304] unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}vendor>,<{}codename>,<{}abi>,<{}api-level>,<{}tag>
C/C++: Could not execute cmake at '/usr/local/bin' to get version. Skipping.
WARNING:C/C++: Could not execute cmake at '/usr/local/bin' to get version. Skipping.
C/C++: Could not execute cmake at '/usr/local/bin' to get version. Skipping.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
Note: /Users/houry/Desktop/MyProject/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/codegen/generator/SchemaJsonParser.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[CXX1300] CMake '3.18.1' was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property.
[CXX1300] CMake '3.18.1' was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> [CXX1300] CMake '3.18.1' was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 42s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: /Users/houry/Desktop/MyProject/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/codegen/generator/SchemaJsonParser.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[CXX1300] CMake '3.18.1' was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property.
[CXX1300] CMake '3.18.1' was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> [CXX1300] CMake '3.18.1' was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 42s
```

I tried to following commends:

1. cd android
2. gradlew clean

but i got the following:
-bash: gradlew: command not found

I tried to modify build.gradle file and changed the version of gradle.
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x").
But i got dependency errors.

Comment: Which react-native version are you using? Seems like there is an issue in configuration of react-native-reanimated library. Please follow this document for installation guide.
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/

Comment: @UbaidUllah Thank you. i am using react-native "0.68.2" and   react-native-reanimated "2.9.1".

Answer (score 0):

Install **CMake** in android studio to fix the issue

1. open sdk manager in android studio.
2. click on SDK Tools.
3. click on show package details.
4. check CMake 3.18.1 and continue